# wget resume download from dropbox gives can't write error

Tags: wget, download

I want to resume download from dropbox using wget. I was downloading a file

```
wget -O SQLyog.exe "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfv2z0le0c2bo7z/SQLyog-9.3.3-0Trial.exe?dl=1"

..........

Length: 15775640 (15M) [application/x-msdos-program]
Saving to: ‘SQLyog.exe’

 5% [====>                  ] 810,391     12.3KB/s  eta 18m 39s
```

The size of file now is

```
lh SQLyog.exe 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 prayagupd prayagupd 1008K Dec 18 18:01 SQLyog.exe
```

When I try to resume the download after interruption; with following command,

```
## with shortened url
wget -O SQLyog.exe --continue "http://bit.ly/1x22r8H"

## or with actual url
wget -O SQLyog.exe --continue "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfv2z0le0c2bo7z/SQLyog-9.3.3-0Trial.exe?dl=1"

..........
Length: 15775640 (15M) [application/x-msdos-program]
Saving to: ‘SQLyog.exe’

 0% [                          ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s      


Cannot write to ‘SQLyog.exe’ (Success).
```

It tells me **Cannot write**, is there anything **I'm missing** to resume this or my script itself is wrong?

[image]

I also tried `--tries=0` but got same error,

```
wget -O SQLyog.exe --continue --tries=0 "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfv2z0le0c2bo7z/SQLyog-9.3.3-0Trial.exe?dl=1"

wget --trust-server-names -O SQLyog.exe --continue --tries=0 "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfv2z0le0c2bo7z/SQLyog-9.3.3-0Trial.exe?dl=1"
```

Without the filename (`-O SQLyog.exe`) it saves to some random file but starting download from scratch again.

**But I tried resume on another link which is working fine.**

```
wget -O ubuntu-14.10-server-powerpc.iso http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/releases/14.10/release/ubuntu-14.10-server-powerpc.iso
```

**followed by,**

```
wget -O ubuntu-14.10-server-powerpc.iso --continue http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/releases/14.10/release/ubuntu-14.10-server-powerpc.iso
```

**Not sure if dropbox server is not allowing this resume service.**

### References

https://askubuntu.com/a/283431/37643

Comment: Some servers aren't able to resume downloads...